# Commit failed - the repository is locked, XCode 7

Tags: swift, git, bitbucket, xcode7

I have a Git - Repository (Bitbucket) for my XCode Project. Since 3 days it doesn't work any more.

The following mistake occurs:

[image]

What could be the mistake? I have no idea ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Xcode, your repo is locked by the server so you can't push updates. See if you need to pay to Bitbucket, payment issues are the usual cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the git lock file from your project's source directory.

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```